# Android EditText not scrolling with soft keyboard input

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

My `EditText` is not scrolling with input from the soft keyboard.

For example, if the `EditText` can display 3 lines of text, when the user enters the 4th line, the cursor and what they are typing is not visible.

However, you can manually scroll down to the invisible text using your finger.

XML:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/tools_free_text_edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="start|top"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:hint=""/>
```

Java:

```
myEditText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
myEditText.setScroller(new Scroller(context));
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your EditText works fine for me. Can you show the rest of your xml and also your AndroidManifest entry for the activity.

Comment: Why did you add Java?